# Find class with a specific property value - and then create instance of this class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, reflection

I have the following class sample:

```
public class ExceptionOne : BaseException
{
    //Define the error bit the exception represents
    public static int ErrorBitNumber = 1234;

    public ExceptionOne()
    {
        //Do something in  the ctor
    }
}
```

(*There is no relevant functionality in `BaseException` so its not necessary to show the code ;)* )

Further there are other exception classes with the property called `ErrorBitNumber` but with other values for the property `ErrorBitNumber`. Each exception class represents an errorbitnumber - so there is always one class for one errorbitnumber.

As i never know which errorbitnumber i receive (*if i receive one*) i want to implement the following -->

- Go thru each existing class which derives from `BaseException` and look for the received error bit number
- If class is found, create an instance of the specific class (*fill some further properties or something*)
- Throw it

I know that this should be possible to implement by using reflection - but truly i don't know how. Further i think using the `ErrorBitNumber` as `public static` should be the right approach. If not, feel free to correct me.

**Update 1:**

For understanding: We have header files which will be parsed. In this header files there are errors defined. For each error a exception class with the specific errorbitnumber will be created. So on the lowest tier in the architecture i receive an error bit number and have to throw the specific exception which represents the specific errorbitnumber

Comment: Don't look for a reflection hack for this.  The proper pattern to use here is the Factory pattern.  Simple and clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all relevant classes derive directly from `BaseException` and are in the same assembly as it, you can use this code:

```
var exceptionType =
    typeof(BaseException)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(BaseException))
        .Select(x => new { ExceptionType = x, Property = x.GetProperty("ErrorBitNumber", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) })
        .Where(x => x.Property != null)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property.GetValue(null, null) == errorBitNumber)
        .ExceptionType;

if(exceptionType == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No matching exception has been found");

var exception = (BaseException)Activator.CreateInstance(exceptionType);
throw exception;
```

This should work, but it is nothing I would ever use. I would create some kind of *exception registry* that can be used to retrieve a new instance of the exception for a specific error bit.

The exception registry can be implemented in a number of ways, mostly depending on your exact needs. The most generic and flexible way would be to simply register factories:

```
public class ExceptionRegistry<TKey, TExceptionBase> where TExceptionBase : Exception
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, Func<TExceptionBase>> _factories = new ...;

    public void Register(TKey key, Func<TExceptionBase> factory)
    {
        _factories[key] = factory;
    }

    public TExceptionBase GetInstance(TKey key)
    {
        Func<TExceptionBase> factory;
        if(!_factories.TryGetValue(key, out factory))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No matching factory has been found");
        return factory();
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
var exception = registry.GetInstance(errorBitNumber);
throw exception;
```

Because it is the most flexible approach, it also is the most verbose approach with regards to actually registering the exception classes:

```
var registry = new ExceptionRegistry<int, BaseException>();
registry.Register(ExceptionOne.ErrorBitNumber, () => new ExceptionOne());
registry.Register(ExceptionTwo.ErrorBitNumber, () => new ExceptionTwo());
registry.Register(ExceptionThree.ErrorBitNumber, () => new ExceptionThree());
```

You basically have to register each exception class manually. However, this has the advantage that you can customize the creation of the exception:

```
registry.Register(ExceptionFour.ErrorBitNumber,
                  () => new ExceptionFour(some, parameters));
```

If you don't want to create a manual registration for each exception class you could combine the two approaches:
You would still use reflection to get all the exception classes. But the result would be used to fill the registry, so that you can use the registry to actually retrieve the instance. Using reflection in this way to create the registry is basically "Convention over Configuration". The big advantage here is that you perform the registration only once, becoming basically infrastructure code. After that, you have a well defined interface - the registry - you can use.

It could look like so:

```
var registry = new ExceptionRegistry<int, BaseException>();
var exceptions = 
    typeof(BaseException)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(BaseException))
        .Select(x => new { ExceptionType = x, Property = x.GetProperty("ErrorBitNumber", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) })
        .Where(x => x.Property != null)
        .Select(x => new { Key = (int)x.Property.GetValue(null, null)
                           Factory = (Func<BaseException>)(() => Activator.CreateInstance(x.ExceptionType)) });
 foreach(var exception in exceptions)
     registry.Register(exception.Key, exception.Factory);
```

Usage to actually get an exception instance would use the registry:

```
var exception = registry.GetInstance(errorBitNumber);
throw exception;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the way i was looking for - but "exception registry" sounds also interesting. Could you please tell me what do you mean with creating an exception registry. Maybe its a better  approach then using reflection.

Comment: Wow, i like the approach with the registry. Thanks for the combination of the two approaches because it can always happen that someone adds new exceptions - so it would not be necessary to add them manually to the registry (for explanation see the update on the main question). Thank you!

Comment: Seems like im missing something at  `(Func<BaseCanUnitErrorException>)() => Activator.CreateInstance(x.ExceptionType) });` From `) => Activator.CreateInstance(x.ExceptionType) });` it is underlined in red

Comment: @DanielW.: Try putting it in parentheses: `(Func<BaseCanUnitErrorException>)(() => Activator.CreateInstance(x.ExceptionType) }));`